Conga: Merging multiple quotes into 1 order form
Use case: I want to amend multiple active contracts on one Account while keeping their distinct dates (not co-terming). The problem is I have to manually merge the documents so the customer can see all of their contracts but only sign one signature page.
Can anyone help me understand how to create a solution to be able to pull in product details from multiple quotes into one order form?

Welcome to SFSE.  Please take a moment to read [ask] and take the [tour].  Your best bet is to check with Conga support.
